# Insert a collection into MongoDB with a json file with a size of 600mb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to import a JSON file into my local database, but there seems to be an issue when trying to import a JSON file larger than a certain size.

From the command prompt I run:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin>mongoimport -d localhost --port=27017 -c users --db=cptechdemolocal --type json --file=C:\data\importdata\users.json --numInsertionWorkers 8
```

This just throws an error of 'Failed: an inserted document is too large'.

Is there a way to do this without splitting the JSON file? Maybe some missing arguments or an alternative method I can look at?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB documents (when serialized to BSON) must not exceed 16 mb. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/.

Inserting a larger document won't work, you need to reorganize your data.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix the issue by adding in --batchSize 1, which completed the import in batches and had no need for me to split the data in my JSON file.